# What is PropertyDescriptor.GetEditor() useful for?

Tags: .net

I just discovered the `PropertyDescriptor` class and I was wondering what is its method `GetEditor()` used for. [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.geteditor.aspx) doesn't say much about it.

So, what kind of editor does it return? How would you use it? Is it actually useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used primarily for the [PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.aspx) control, or third party versions. It returns a value specified on the property or type by the [EditorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorattribute.aspx).

It actually returns an instance of the type specified by EditorAttribute.

For the WinForms PropertyGrid, the editors derive from [UITypeEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor.aspx). Third-party property grids can have their own base type though.

In general, you'd create editors for your types/properties and won't need to call GetEditor.